# Maximal intersections for loop with even number of segments

Tags: geometry

An even number of line segments connected end-to-end form a loop. The maximal number of intersection points is 1, 7, 17, 31, 49, 71, ..., assuming that we disregard segments that overlap with infinitely many points in common. Why always one less than double a square number? Source: [James Tanton](https://twitter.com/jamestanton/status/1663491188823937024). I've been trying to figure this out all day. I think it has something to do with the fact that when you cross certain lines, you have to cross them on the way back. I can always construct the supposed maximal number of intersections, but I can't prove they're maximal and would like help doing so.
[image]

Comment: @YNK I added the link. I believe your comment solves the problem. I'm not sure why your claims are true, aside from p = m - 3, which is true because a segment can't cross itself, nor the two segments it's adjacent to. Are you willing to submit an answer with a bit more detail?

Comment: I don’t know whether you have already noticed the following fact. Assume that the maximum number of points of intersections a given segment can have is $p$. There are exactly two such segments. Each of the remaining segments has only $p-1$ number of points of intersections.   If there are $m$ number of segments, then $p=m-3$. Therefore, the maximum number of points of intersections is equal to $\dfrac{m^2}{2}-2m+1$. By the way, can you please give us the link to the mentioned source?

Comment: Thank you for adding the link. I do not think I have solved the problem. Other than the formula $p=m-3$, the rest of my statements are all observations only. For instance, I have not proved that there can only be two segments with $p$ number of points of intersections or each remaining segment has only $p-1$ number of points of intersections. I am sorry that I deleted my comment by mistake. I have added it again. I am still trying to justify James Tanton’s assertion

Comment: You're welcome and no worries about the accidental delete. I hope you can solve it. I'll ping you here if I receive more info from Twitter.

Comment: @YNK A proof was released on Twitter! If you're able to clean it up and post it here I'll accept it as an answer. I'm sure Bob Ruyle would like to see any progress on Twitter but I'm not sure if you're on there.

Comment: Thanks for informing me about the answer on Twitter. The accepted practise at StackExchange in this type of situation is to post a link to the answer published on Twitter, especially for the benefit of non-twitting folk.

Comment: @YNK Thanks for letting me know. Here it is: https://twitter.com/bruyle1/status/1665714808497356802